# Large error when numerically computing second derivative

Tags: r, poisson

I'm trying to numerically take the second derivative of a function `l` (the log of the Poisson distribution over vector `x` and `lambda=6`) in R and this is my code:

```
    x=c(2,3)
    t=6
    delta=1e-12
    h=1e-12

    L=function(x,t) dpois(x,t)
    l<-function(x,t) log(prod(L(x,t)))
    ld<-function(x,t) (l(x,t+delta)-l(x,t))/delta
    ldd<-function(x,t) (ld(x,t+h)-ld(x,t))/h
    ld(x,t)
    ldd(x,t)
```

My output is

```
> ld(x,t)
[1] -1.167066
> ldd(x,t)
[1] 888178420
```

But for this exact same function I use wolfram and get [-7/6~~-1.16667](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=first%20derivative%20of%20log%28x%5E5%20e%5E%28-2x%29%2F%282%213%21%29%29%20at%20x%3D6) for the first derivative and [-5/36~~-0.138889](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second%20derivative%20of%20log%28x%5E5%20e%5E%28-2x%29%2F%282%213%21%29%29%20at%20x%3D6) for the second derivative.  I've been trying to figure out why my function has such a large error for the last two hours.

Note:  This is for a class project so I can't use the derivative function in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issues you are seeing are due to roundoff and other numerical issues. I would suggest two approaches:

1. Increase your `delta` and `h` values; since your computer has finite precision, in many cases `t` and `t+1e-12` will be exactly the same. Of course, this causes big issues when numerically calculating derivatives.
2. For numerical stability, it is typically a good idea to replace `log(prod(x))` with `sum(log(x))`.

With these two adjustments, we get much nicer results:

```
delta = 1e-5
h = 1e-4
L=function(x,t) dpois(x,t)
l<-function(x,t) sum(log(L(x,t)))
ld<-function(x,t) (l(x,t+delta)-l(x,t))/delta
ldd<-function(x,t) (ld(x,t+h)-ld(x,t))/h
ld(x,t)
# [1] -1.166667
ldd(x,t)
# [1] -0.1388853
```